# Literature on BFGS

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

so I have some questions and am looking for some papers to read for my own knowledge and understanding. So one may think of BFGS as poor man Newton method in terms of convergence, requires less but it is objectively slower. I have read on BFGS and have seen that one may prove the method by solving a minimization problem

http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2007/09/1789.pdf

I have also read a bit on Newton, and I have seen it been proven as a fix point problem. My question is can we think of the BFGS as a fix point problem and are there any papers proving the BFGS using the fix point theorem?

Comment: Requires less in the sense that you don't have to calculate as many things so you can do more iterations in same amount of time.

Comment: Correct, we do not need second derivative information

Comment: And partial second derivatives are square the number of dimensions. It quickly starts to become troublesome to calculate. So there can be lots of time to save which lets us do many more iterations instead.